# Refractive Index of a Aspheric lens

Tags: optics, refraction, diffraction, lenses

I have the following specifications of an aspheric lens:

> AL5040-B - Ø50 mm S-LAH64, f = 40 mm, NA = 0.54, ARC: 650-1050 nm

Is there a way to calculate or identify the refractive index of the lens using this information?
I need the refractive index to calculate the angle of diffraction when a laser beam passes through the lens.

I also have this relation:

> $\frac{x}{f} = tan(\phi)$

where,
x is the radial distance by which the lens diffracts rays w.r.t. the center of the lens

and, f is the focal length.

[image]

Comment: S-LAH64 is the glass it's made of. Googling this name, you'll find the specs including refractive indices. OTOH, I'm not sure you really need refractive index for your calculations. How exactly do you suppose to use it?

Comment: I was planning to use the equation $NA = n sin \theta$. `NA` is `0.54` from the data given and once I have `n`, I can calculate $\theta$.
Is there another way to calculate the diffraction angle?

Comment: $n$ here must be the refractive index of the medium *in which the lens works*, not the material the lens is made of. See e.g. [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_aperture#General_optics).

Comment: On the right side of this page, it says because of Snell's law, $NA = n sin\theta$ can be used as well. So if $\theta$ is the diffraction angle, `n` would have to be the refractive index of the lens itself. This was my thinking.

Comment: The light from laser originates in air, and after exiting the lens it's still in air. The $\theta_2$ that's mentioned under that image in Wikipedia is about the angle inside the lens. But you never use the light until it exits the lens. After that you still need $\theta_1$.

Comment: Oh! I did not notice that. Then what would be the best way to calculate the diffraction angle? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It depends on your actual setup. Why is diffraction the dominant effect? Are you trying to collimate the laser light, or what?

Comment: I am actually making a mathematical model and have to model the rays from the laser. For that, I have to understand how the lens is changing the path of the rays. Then I will be able to represent the rays mathematically.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure ray optics is a useful model for laser light, when you want to account for diffraction. Laser light is usually modelled as a [gaussian beam](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/lasers/gaussian-beam-propagation/), where diffraction is a built-in feature.

Comment: Ok! I will check the Gaussian beam method out! Thank you!